# Cant initiate break points with Xdebug through dbgpProxy on multi-site dev server

Tags: apache2, php, vpn, aws, xdebug

I manage a setup with multiple developers using a "developer" Apache Server with PHP 7.4.

Since the Ubuntu 20.04 server is running in a private range in AWS, access is only allowed thru a VPN server. The VPN server is also where we have the dbgpProxy running as it can see both the workstations and the Dev Apache Server.

Our AWS instances are set up to allow all 9000-9010 traffic thru bi-directionally from each box.

This is the /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.discover_client_host = yes
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.client_host = <<IP ADDRESS OF VPN SERVER>>
xdebug.client_port = 9003
xdebug.log = /var/tmp/php74-xdebug.log
xdebug.log_level = 5
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
```

I have tried the above without the discover_client_host line too, but that did not help.

The execution of the dbgpProxy on the VPN server looks like this:
`./dbgpProxy -i 0.0.0.0:9003 -s 0.0.0.0:9001`

Once executed, the output looks like this:

```
Xdebug DBGp proxy (0.4.2-dev)
Copyright 2020 by Derick Rethans
2022-09-14 19:26:53.893 [warn] [SSL] The 'certs/fullchain.pem' file could not be found, not enabling SSL listeners
2022-09-14 19:26:53.894 [info] [dbgpProxy] Proxy started
2022-09-14 19:26:53.894 [info] [server] Started client server on 0.0.0.0:9003
2022-09-14 19:26:53.894 [info] [server] Started server server on 0.0.0.0:9001
2022-09-14 19:26:59.516 [info] [server] Start new client connection from <<VPN IP ADDRESS>>:53841
2022-09-14 19:27:00.020 [info] [proxyinit] [MATT] Added connection for IDE Key '<<DEVIDKEY>>': <<VPN IP ADDRESS>>:9001
2022-09-14 19:27:00.020 [info] [server] Closing client connection from <<VPN IP ADDRESS>>:53841
2022-09-14 19:27:15.480 [info] [server] Start new client connection from <<APACHE BOX IP>>:42144
2022-09-14 19:27:15.480 [warn] [server] Handler response error: Error reading command: Don't understand command '[494]'
2022-09-14 19:27:15.480 [info] [server] Closing client connection from <<APACHE BOX IP>>:42144
```

I have been testing and testing small changes for a long time now and I am getting no nearer a solution. I have tried checking out those Handler response errors in google too, but have not found any other posts about this with any information. Can anyone help me?
Thanks!